# Django unable to create default table using "python manage.py syncdb" command

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. I am following the instructions given in the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).
When I am running `python manage.py syncdb`, I am getting the following error:

```
D:\MyDev\DjnagoProject\mysite>python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 420, in execute_from_command_
line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\dummy\base.py", line 15, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("You haven't set the database ENGINE setting yet.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You haven't set the database ENGINE setting yet.
```

Adding information :
Python version : 2.7.2, 
django version : (1, 4, 0, 'alpha', 1)
OS : windows XP

Please let me know where I am making a mistake.

Comment: I don't know which tutorial you are following but the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup) clearly mentions to setup database engine first and than run `python manage.py syncdb`.

Comment: I am also following the same document which you have mentioned here. this is database value which i have modified as per my requirement in setting.py file                                            DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': r'D:/MyDev/DjnagoProject/mysite/myDev.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.

Comment: Show us the content of settings.py file relevant to the database section. And also which database you are using I suggest you use sqlite3 which is in-built for python >2.5

Answer (score 5):

Read your error messages:

> ImproperlyConfigured: **You haven't set the database ENGINE setting
>   yet.**

Check [`DATABASES` in your `settings.py`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-DATABASES). You need at least [`ENGINE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#engine) and [database `NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#name)

Comment: it's either not loading your settings or you have not set the database engine setting.

Comment: can you please suggest what should i do? As i have tried to set PYTHONPOATH as well but no result. It will be great if you can suggest some alternative..

Comment: @vartec: Isn't these things happen by default when you do `pip install django`. It happened for me

Comment: Do i need to setup PythonPath or DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE path in my system environment?

Answer (score 1):

```
You haven't set the database ENGINE setting yet.
```

Make sure you have correct [DB credentials in settings.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-DATABASES).

Answer (score 1):

you need to do following two things in settings.py

1. add database engine and credentials in database dictionary.

> ```
> DATABASES = {
>     'default': {
>         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqllite3',
>         'NAME': '/home/yourname/mydb', 
>         'USER': '',   
>         'PASSWORD': '',  
>         'HOST': '',        
>         'PORT': '',  
> }
> }
> ```

1. add your app to installed_app list

> ```
> INSTALLED_APPS = (
>     'com.example.myapp',
>     ....
> ```

Comment: I am still getting the same error.                            DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':"sqlite3",
        'NAME':r"D:/MyDev/DjnagoProject/mysite/myDev.db",
        'USER':'',
        'PASSWORD':'',
        'HOST':'',
        'PORT':'',
    }
}                                                       INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mysite.blog',

)   I have created blog application inside the mysite.

Answer (score 1):

I addition to database configuration in settings.py file:

Now on **Django 1.8.x**, it fully supports **migrations**.

**syncdb** will be fully removed in version 1.9

Try to use **makemigrations** and **migrate** instead

```
python manage.py makemigrations app1 app2 app3
```

will make migration scripts in each app migration folder

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Will look at database **django_migrations** table and migrations folder and will migrate the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Install MySQL-python worked for me!