# Django installation error on python 2.7 (centOs 6.8)

Tags: django, python-2.7, centos6

Have a trouble with Django installation and unfortunately had not find any information about the same bug in the net. When I try to do first migration of django database I had such an output:

```
> python manage.py migrate Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/etc/network/scripts/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 367, in execute_from_command_line
>     utility.execute()   File "/etc/network/scripts/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
> line 359, in execute
>     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "/etc/network/scripts/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 294, in run_from_argv
>     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "/etc/network/scripts/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 345, in execute
>     output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "/etc/network/scripts/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py",
> line 83, in handle
>     executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)   File
> "/etc/network/scripts/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py",
> line 20, in __init__
>     self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)   File "/etc/network/scripts/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
> line 52, in __init__
>     self.build_graph()   File "/etc/network/scripts/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py",
> line 203, in build_graph
>     self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()   File "/etc/network/scripts/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py",
> line 65, in applied_migrations
>     self.ensure_schema()   File "/etc/network/scripts/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py",
> line 59, in ensure_schema
>     raise MigrationSchemaMissing("Unable to create the django_migrations table (%s)" % exc)
> django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to
> create the django_migrations table (near "BGN": syntax error)
```

This *"BGN": syntax error* I didn't find anywhere. The same problem with pip installation or from the sources, either in venv or without it. Any ideas how this issue could be solved?

Comment: looks like a connection issue with DB. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683650/django-unable-to-create-default-table-using-python-manage-py-syncdb-command

Comment: and try  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691932/migrationschemamissingunable-to-create-the-django-migrations-table-s-exc

Comment: Part of my configuration DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

Comment: File db.sqlite3 is created in venv directory, but then I couldn't make runserver, have the same error. Maybe some problem with engine? How I could debug it?

Comment: Unfortunatly I have not postgresql, only sqlite. So seems it is not my case.

Comment: I tried to use mysql instead of sqlite and all is ok. So seems this case could be closed.